# Robot framework - How do I see the output of a command executed in a shell?

Tags: docker, process, robotframework

I would like to use the Robot framework to automate a step where the next command is executed in a cmd:

`docker-compose logs --no-color --tail=1 the-server`

The output of the previous command will be the log of the server named the-server in the docker-compose.yml file.

After I would like to check if the response of this command has the string `Started the-server`, to check if the server is up.

I'm using the next robot file:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Process
Library    OperatingSystem
Suite Setup    log    running on ${properties.hostname}    
Suite Teardown    Terminate All Processes    kill=True

Variables    C:/Users/TheUser/Desktop/CheckOutRegression/properties.py

*** Test Cases ***
Check if the-server is up
    ${result}    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    10x    20s    Check The-Server
*** Keyword ***
Check The-Server
    ${resultOfcmd}    Run Process    docker-compose logs --no-color --tail\=1 the-server   shell=yes    cwd=${properties.pathToDocker}
    Should Contain    ${resultOfcmd}    'Started the-server'    PASS
    Log To Console    ${resultOfcmd}
```

The test-case is always failing with the error:

> Keyword 'Check The-Server' failed after retrying 10 times. The last error was: TypeError: 'ExecutionResult' object is not iterable

also I'm not sure if the variable `{resultOfcmd}` contains the output of the command `docker-compose logs --no-color --tail\=1 the-server`.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Process library documentation about Result object from Run Process keyword:

https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Result%20object

You get your results from `${resultOfcmd.stdout}`.

You should also use Log To Console before failing keyword to see result before test fails.

Answer (score 0):

Log To Console ${resultOfcmd.stdout} console=yes